# How to use Babel without Webpack

Tags: reactjs, webpack, babeljs, watch, transpiler

I'm making an `electron.js` using `React`. I'm using JSX so need to use `Babel` to transpile. Many tutorials out there all suggests using Webpack.

Currently, I'm using `Webpack 4`. Here is my `webpack.config.js`

```
const path = require('path')

module.exports = {
  entry: "./src/renderer.js",
  output: {
    path: path.resolve(__dirname, "dist"),
    filename: "renderer.js"
  },
  module: {
    rules: [
      {
        test: /\.js$/,
        exclude: /node_modules/,
        use: {
          loader: 'babel-loader'
        }
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

And my `.babelrc`

```
{
  "presets": ["es2015", "stage-0", "react"]
}
```

Here I need to start with `renderer.js` because it contains most of my code and `React` components, the result is a bundled js file.

But all I want is to transpile all my `jsx` files to normal `js` files, something like transpile all JSX files within `src` to there according JS files in `dist` folders, and if available, watch and transpile when I edit the files. How to achieve that?

Comment: And why you don't want `webpack` to do that? I don't really understand the reason :)

Comment: This is what I need https://babeljs.io/docs/usage/cli/#compile-directories

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can simply run babel through the command line:

`babel --plugins transform-react-jsx-source script.js`

Docs: 
https://babeljs.io/docs/plugins/transform-react-jsx-source/

> Note the three "Usages" on the page. All of them will get you what you want, none of them use `webpack`. The `.babelrc`file can handle all your plugins/transforms and is the recommended usage. Then you just run `babel`

Here is an example from Material-UI's [package.json](https://github.com/mui-org/material-ui/blob/1b1c1fce216b5b2f5ecd52d21f8ec6a326c00cd5/package.json#L28):

```
"build:es2015": "cross-env NODE_ENV=production babel ./src --ignore *.spec.js --out-dir ./build",
```